# Cursor Hand Symbol Change

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am having a Gridview.In that ther are 2 columns,like Image and Status. In image columns some of the images will be disabled. For that,the Cursor Hand Symbol should not come.How to change this. Here is my code...

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="List.ascx.cs"
Inherits="List" %>
 <style type="text/css">
 .noHand 
 {
  cursor:default
 } 
 </style>
 ..........
 .........
  <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Image" ShowEditButton="True" HeaderText="Edit"        EditImageUrl="~/IMAGES/Edit.gif">
   <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
   </asp:CommandField>
```

Code Behind

```
protected void Grid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{  
       if (Status.Value == "True")
        {
           //Here Cursor Hand symbol should come
        }
        else
        {
          e.Row.Cells[9].CssClass = "nohand";
        }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using the CssClass property on the cells:

```
e.Row.Cells[cellIndex].CssClass = "nohand";
```

`cellIndex` being a zero based index of your cells on each row.

Then create a css class in your existing stylesheet (or create a new stylesheet and reference it from your application) called `nohand` that includes the rule `cursor:default;`.

Comment: <style type="text/css"> .noHand {cursor:default} </style> .... This is my CSS. How can i use this in my RowDataBound

Comment: You'll add that css to a stylesheet which is referenced by your ASP.NET application.  You'll then use the code in my answer above in your Grid_RowDataBound.  By itself, it will show the default cursor for all images, so you'll want to wrap it in a check to see whether the image is "disabled" or not.

Comment: Well, there's only two things that could be wrong.  Your check is incorrect (Status.Value is not returning what you think it is) and/or you're not correctly including the css rule.  You can set a breakpoint and test, for the first condition, and you can use a tool like Firebug to confirm your css class exists and that the table cell has the appropriate class on it.

Comment: i had given <style type="text/css"> .noHand {cursor:default} </style> in my ascx file itself. whether i should i give like this..

Answer (score 2):

You'd have to link up with a CSS Class that has the cursor property set.  Wherever you have code to emit a disabled image command, also put out some css that sets your cursor accordingly.

http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_class_cursor.asp

So create a CSS class something like this:

```
noHand {cursor:default}
```

And make sure it's set for disabled columns.  @Nick's answer looks like it would do just that.

Comment: While moving the cursor on the Gridview, if the image is disabled the default cursor should appear or if the image is enabled Hand symbol should appear. OnMouseOver, these should be happen

Comment: <style type="text/css">
.noHand {cursor:default} 
</style> .... This is my CSS. How can i use this in my RowDataBound